Cartoon where heroes drive a Blue and a Pink race car
I have a feeling this was from the late 80's (uk) and I think I can remember watching inspector gadget at around the same time growing up.
It was a cartoon with two lead heroes who might have been spies/agents, male drove a blue sports car and the women drove a pink one
Can't remember any other details unfortunately 

That sounds like Pole Position. It ran for one season in 1984. The protagonists were stunt drivers whose cars talked and sported lots of gadgets. When they weren't doing their stunt show the drivers helped people who were in trouble and/or thwarted the plans of bad guys. The blue car was named Roadie, and the red (not pink) car was Wheels.


Awesome that's the exact one I was thinking of, thanks so much
